# Proof-checking proof of Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, banach-spaces, sequence-of-function

> Let $C([a,b],\mathbb{C})$ be all continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with  a complex image. Show that it is a Banach space with respect to $\|f_n\|_\infty=\max_{x\in[a,b]}\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid|f_n(x)|\}$.

Let $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ be a Cauchy sequence in the normed vector space. Then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m\ge N$. Next I'll use the lemma

> Lemma 1: Let $f_n:A\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ . $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ converges uniformly iff $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Since $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ is also uniformly convergent towards $f$.

**Edit**: We prove that this $f$ exists. For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $$|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\le\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty<\epsilon$$ for all $n,m\ge N$. Since $\left(f_m(x)\right)_{n\ge 1}$ is a complex Cauchy sequence, there exists some convergence point. Let that be $\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)=f(x)$.

Then for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f-f_n\|_\infty<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. Now that I've shown completeness, I show that $f$ is in the normed vector space.

> Lemma 2: Let $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of functions defined on $A$ and assume that $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ converges uniformly towards $f$ on $A$. Then $f$ is continuous on $A$.

Since $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ is defined as continues functions on $[a,b]$ and the convergence towards $f$ is uniformly, we can conclude that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and thus it is in the normed vector space per definition of the vector space.

Would this suffice as a proof?

Comment: Lemma 1 is written in an odd way, I think it should be "$f_n$ converges uniformly iff ...".

Comment: Lost in translation. I'll fix it.

Comment: Something's wrong in your def'n of the norm, as it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't suffice. What is that function $f$ that you mention? You must explain first what $f$ is and then to prove that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: The function $f$ is the function that the sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ converges to uniformly. How would you suggest that is make this explicit?

Comment: @bubububub How do you know that such a function exists? That's what you are supposed to prove!

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @bubububub It's better, but you did not prove that $f\in C([a,b],\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Is that not what I've done in the end using lemma 2?

Comment: @bubububub But you did **not** prove that the convergence is uniform. You only stated that it is, withou a proof.

Comment: Sorry for the many comments but I'm not getting it. We have a Cauchy sequence of functions. Using lemma 1, we know that it is uniformly convergent, since it is a Cauchy sequence. What's there to prove?

Comment: @bubububub Are you allowed to use lemma 1 without proving it? If so, then, yes, your proof is finished. Nevertheless, I find that quite strange, since lemma 1 is essentially the very statement that you are supposed to prove.

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to use it - we've proved it earlier in the course. Thank you very much for your time.